# How do I draw a line on the INNER margin in a double-sided document?

Tags: double-sided, mdframed

With the `mdframed` package one can draw nice lines on the left or right of the text. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} 

\mdfdefinestyle{MDFStyGrayBar}{%
    linecolor=gray,
    backgroundcolor=white,
    %
    outerlinewidth=5pt,
    %
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    rightline=false,
    leftline=true,
    %
    innertopmargin=4pt, %\baselineskip
    innerbottommargin=8pt,
    innerrightmargin=3pt,
    innerleftmargin=3pt,
    %
    skipabove=\topskip,
    skipbelow=\topskip
}

\begin{document}

\noindent Some normal text.
\begin{mdframed}[style=MDFStyGrayBar]
Some text with a vertical bar on the left.
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

looks like this:

[image: output]

But what if I want the line to be on the *inner* side in a double-sided ("twoside") document? That is, on the left for a right-page and on the right for a left-page? This should also work, when the frame extends over several pages. Is that possible with the mdframed package?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115003/8528) do anything like what you want? (Note: it relies on `geometry`.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @jon: I can't see any relations to your linked question.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel -- I don't follow; are you suggesting I delete the comment?  The answer is surely related to some degree: it draws a line on the margins. And I implied (at least) that it doesn't use your package.  I didn't post it as an answer because it clearly doesn't answer the question vis-à-vis the specific reference to `mdframed`. But cross-linking answers in comments seems to me to increase the utility of TeX.SX in general because future readers may decide the linked-to answers were actually the one(s) they were looking for.  (It's not like I was voting to close or anything....)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel -- Great! That hack does the job! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mdframed` detects whether it is used inside twoside mode. If it's true you can adjust length by `innermargin` and `outermargin`. The hack below adds some options to the original definition. If you are on an odd page the setting `\mdfsetup{hidealllines=true,leftline=true}` is used. On the other hand `\mdfsetup{hidealllines=true,rightline=true}` is used.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} 
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*\if@mdf@pageodd@bar{%
 \zref@refused{mdf@pagelabel-\the\value{mdf@zref@counter}}%
 \ifodd\zref@extract{mdf@pagelabel-\the\value{mdf@zref@counter}}%
                    {mdf@pagevalue}%
    \setlength\mdf@rightmargin@length{\mdf@outermargin@length}%
    \setlength\mdf@leftmargin@length{\mdf@innermargin@length}%
    \mdfsetup{hidealllines=true,leftline=true}%
 \else
    \setlength\mdf@rightmargin@length{\mdf@innermargin@length}%
    \setlength\mdf@leftmargin@length{\mdf@outermargin@length}%
    \mdfsetup{hidealllines=true,rightline=true}%
 \fi%
}
\newrobustcmd*\changepageodd{\let\if@mdf@pageodd\if@mdf@pageodd@bar}
\makeatother
\mdfdefinestyle{MDFStyGrayBar}{%
    linecolor=gray,
    backgroundcolor=white,
    %
    outerlinewidth=5pt,
    %
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    rightline=false,
    leftline=true,
    %
    innertopmargin=4pt, %\baselineskip
    innerbottommargin=8pt,
    innerrightmargin=3pt,
    innerleftmargin=3pt,
    %
    skipabove=\topskip,
    skipbelow=\topskip,
    settings={\changepageodd}
}
\usepackage{showframe,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\noindent Some normal text.
\begin{mdframed}[style=MDFStyGrayBar]
\lipsum
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]