# Line with left margin and vertically centered text from environment using mdframed package

Tags: vertical-alignment, mdframed, leftmargin

I am using the `mdframed` package to put vertical lines in some paragraphs.

But I want the text to have a 2cm left margin and all the text to be centered vertically. Neither is working. How could I do it?

#### Code

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}

% -------------------------------------------------------Packages
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[showframe, pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{mdframed}
% -------------------------------------------------------Book layout
\setstocksize{9in}{6in}
\settrimmedsize{9in}{6in}{*}
\setbinding{0.5in}
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.5in}{0.4in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.5in}{0.5in}{*}
\setheadfoot{12.07pt}{\footskip}
\checkandfixthelayout

% -------------------------------------------------------Global settings
%\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

% -------------------------------------------------------Fonts definition
\newfontfamily\notoserif{Noto Serif}        
\setmainfont{LinuxLibertineO}
\setsansfont{Ubuntu}

% -------------------------------------------------------Heading formats and styles
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\centering\normalfont} 
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\centering\huge\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand\secheadstyle{\scshape\centering\huge\sffamily\noindent}
\renewcommand\subsecheadstyle{\centering\Large\sffamily\bfseries\noindent}
\renewcommand\subsubsecheadstyle{\centering\large\sffamily\noindent\ruleline}
\setsecnumdepth{none}
\nouppercaseheads

\makeevenhead{headings}{\sffamily \scriptsize \thepage {\enspace \textemdash \enspace}\rightmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{headings}{}{}{\sffamily \scriptsize \leftmark {\enspace \textemdash \enspace} \thepage}
\makeevenfoot{headings}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{headings}{}{}{}

% Defined commands
%--------------------------------------------------------------------- Commands

\newcommand{\redtext}[1]{\renewcommand{\redtext}{#1}}
\newcommand{\smalltext}[1]{\renewcommand{\smalltext}{#1}}
\newcommand{\txtred}{\textcolor{red}}
\newcommand{\bfred}{\textcolor{red}}
\newcommand{\rred}{\mbox{}\hfill\txtred}
\newcommand{\h}{\hspace{5mm}}
\newcommand{\hl}{\hspace{10mm}}
\newcommand{\txtsmall}{\small}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------Body styles
\newenvironment{body}{%
    \addvspace{\topsep}% Space above
}{%
    \unskip\par
    \addvspace{\topsep}% Space below
    %\needspace{15\baselineskip}
}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------Pater styles

\newcommand{\ptheme}[1]{
    {   
        \itshape
        %\tiny
        \centering
        \color{red} #1
        \smallskip
        
    }
}


\newenvironment{patercite}{%
    \vspace*{\fill}%
    \sffamily
    \scriptsize 
    \noindent
    \ignorespaces
    \begin{mdframed}[leftmargin =+2cm,linewidth=1.5,linecolor=red, topline=false,rightline=false,bottomline=false]\relax}{%
\end{mdframed}}{% 
    \vspace*{\fill}%
}

\newcommand{\src}[1]{
    {   
        \sffamily
        \tiny
        \centering
        \color{red}\centering #1    
    }
    \par
}

\newcommand*\ruleline[1]{\par\noindent\raisebox{.8ex}{\makebox[\linewidth]{\hrulefill\hspace{1ex}\raisebox{-.8ex}{#1}\hspace{1ex}\hrulefill}}}

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
    \mainmatter

\section{Comentarios Patrísticos}

\subsection{San Cirilo de Alejandría, obispo}

\ptheme{Hablaban de la muerte que Jesús iba a consumar en Jerusalén}
\src{ Homilía 9 en la transfiguración del Señor: PG 77, 1011-1014.}

\begin{body}
    Jesús subió a una montaña con sus tres discípulos preferidos. Allí se transfiguró en un resplandor tan extraordinario y divino, que su vestido parecía hecho de luz. Se les aparecieron también Moisés y Elías conversando con Jesús: hablaban de su muerte, que iba a consumar en Jerusalén, o sea, del misterio de aquella salvación que había de operarse mediante su cuerpo, de aquella pasión –repito– que habría de consumarse en la cruz. Pues la verdad es que la ley de Moisés y los vaticinios de los santos profetas preanunciaron el misterio de Cristo: las losas de la ley lo describían como en imagen y veladamente; los profetas, en cambio, lo predicaron en distintas ocasiones y de muchas maneras, diciendo que en el momento oportuno aparecería en forma humana y aceptaría morir en la cruz por la salvación y la vida de todos.
    
    Y el hecho de que estuviesen allí presentes Moisés y Elías conversando con Jesús, quería indicar que la ley y los profetas son como los dos aliados de nuestro Señor Jesucristo, presentado por ellos como Dios a través de las cosas que habían preanunciado y que concordaban entre sí. En efecto, no disuenan de la ley los vaticinios de los profetas: y, a mi modo de ver, de esto hablaban Moisés y Elías, el más grande de los profetas.
    
    Habiéndose aparecido, no se mantuvieron en silencio, sino que hablaban de la gloria que el mismo Jesús iba a consumar en Jerusalén, a saber, de la pasión y de la cruz y, en ellas, vislumbraban también la resurrección. Pensando quizá el bienaventurado Pedro que había llegado el tiempo del reinado de Dios, gustoso se quedaría a vivir en la montaña; de hecho, y sin saber lo que decía, propone la construcción de tres tiendas. Pero aún no había llegado el fin de los tiempos, ni en la presente vida entrarán los santos a participar de la esperanza a ellos prometida. Dice, en efecto, Pablo: \textit{El trasformará nuestra condición humilde, según el modelo de su condición gloriosa}, es decir, de la condición gloriosa de Cristo.
    
    Ahora bien, estando estos planes todavía en sus comienzos, sin haber llegado aún a su culminación, sería una incongruencia que Cristo, que por amor había venido al mundo, abandonase el proyecto de padecer voluntariamente por él. Conservó, pues, aquella naturaleza infraceleste, con la que padeció la muerte según la carne y la borró por su resurrección de entre los muertos.
    
    Por lo demás y al margen de este admirable y arcano espectáculo de la gloria de Cristo, ocurrió además otro hecho útil y necesario para consolidar la fe en Cristo, no sólo de los discípulos, sino también de nosotros mismos. Allí, en lo alto, resonó efectivamente la voz del Padre que decía: \textit{Este es mi Hijo, el amado, mi predilecto. Escuchadlo}.
\end{body}

\begin{patercite}(\ldots) Éste es el misterio, saludable para nosotros, que ahora se ha cumplido en la montaña, ya que ahora nos reúne la muerte y, al mismo tiempo, la festividad de Cristo. Por esto, para que podamos penetrar, junto con los elegidos entre los discípulos inspirados por Dios, el sentido profundo de estos inefables y sagrados misterios, escuchemos la voz divina y sagrada que nos llama con insistencia desde lo alto, desde la cumbre de la montaña.
    
    Debemos apresurarnos a ir hacia allí –así me atrevo a decirlo– como Jesús, que allí en el cielo es nuestro guía y precursor, con quien brillaremos con nuestra mirada espiritualizada, renovados en cierta manera en los trazos de nuestra alma, hechos conformes a su imagen, y, como él, transfigurados continuamente y hechos partícipes de la naturaleza divina, y dispuestos para los dones celestiales.
    
    Corramos hacia allí, animosos y alegres, y penetremos en la intimidad de la nube, a imitación de Moisés y Elías, o de Santiago y Juan. Seamos como Pedro, arrebatado por la visión y aparición divina, transfigurado por aquella hermosa transfiguración, desasido del mundo, abstraído de la tierra; despojémonos de lo carnal, dejemos lo creado y volvámonos al Creador, al que Pedro, fuera de sí, dijo: \textit{Señor, ¡qué bien se está aquí!}
    
    Ciertamente, Pedro, en verdad qué bien se está aquí con Jesús; aquí nos quedaríamos para siempre. ¿Hay algo más dichoso, más elevado, más importante que estar con Dios, ser hechos conformes con él, vivir en la luz? Cada uno de nosotros, por el hecho de tener a Dios en sí y de ser transfigurado en su imagen divina, tiene derecho a exclamar con alegría: \textit{¡Qué bien se está aquí!} donde todo es resplandeciente, donde está el gozo, la felicidad y la alegría, donde el corazón disfruta de absoluta tranquilidad, serenidad y dulzura, donde vemos a (Cristo) Dios, donde él, junto con el Padre, pone su morada y dice, al entrar: \textit{Hoy ha sido la salvación de esta casa,} donde con Cristo se hallan acumulados los tesoros de los bienes eternos, donde hallamos reproducidas, como en un espejo, las imágenes de las realidades futuras.
    
    \textbf{Anastasio Sinaíta}, \textit{Sermón} en el día de la Transfiguración del Señor, 6-10: \textquote{Mélanges d’archeologie et d’histoire} 67 [1955], 241-244 (Breviario, 6 de agosto).
\end{patercite}

\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]

I want something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is a solution with `tcolorbox` acceptable?

To vertical center the `patercite` environment I've used

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
    \BeforeBeginEnvironment{patercite}{\vspace*{\fill}}
    \AfterEndEnvironment{patercite}{\vspace*{\fill}\mbox{}}
```

Here is the complete code:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}

% -------------------------------------------------------Packages
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[showframe, pass]{geometry}
% -------------------------------------------------------Book layout
\setstocksize{9in}{6in}
\settrimmedsize{9in}{6in}{*}
\setbinding{0.5in}
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.5in}{0.4in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.5in}{0.5in}{*}
\setheadfoot{12.07pt}{\footskip}
\checkandfixthelayout

% -------------------------------------------------------Global settings
%\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

% -------------------------------------------------------Fonts definition
\newfontfamily\notoserif{Noto Serif}        
\setmainfont{LinuxLibertineO}
\setsansfont{Ubuntu}

% -------------------------------------------------------Heading formats and styles
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\centering\normalfont} 
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\centering\huge\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand\secheadstyle{\scshape\centering\huge\sffamily\noindent}
\renewcommand\subsecheadstyle{\centering\Large\sffamily\bfseries\noindent}
\renewcommand\subsubsecheadstyle{\centering\large\sffamily\noindent\ruleline}
\setsecnumdepth{none}
\nouppercaseheads

\makeevenhead{headings}{\sffamily \scriptsize \thepage {\enspace \textemdash \enspace}\rightmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{headings}{}{}{\sffamily \scriptsize \leftmark {\enspace \textemdash \enspace} \thepage}
\makeevenfoot{headings}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{headings}{}{}{}

% Defined commands
%--------------------------------------------------------------------- Commands

\newcommand{\redtext}[1]{\renewcommand{\redtext}{#1}}
\newcommand{\smalltext}[1]{\renewcommand{\smalltext}{#1}}
\newcommand{\txtred}{\textcolor{red}}
\newcommand{\bfred}{\textcolor{red}}
\newcommand{\rred}{\mbox{}\hfill\txtred}
\newcommand{\h}{\hspace{5mm}}
\newcommand{\hl}{\hspace{10mm}}
\newcommand{\txtsmall}{\small}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------Body styles
\newenvironment{body}{%
    \addvspace{\topsep}% Space above
}{%
    \unskip\par
    \addvspace{\topsep}% Space below
    %\needspace{15\baselineskip}
}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------Pater styles

\newcommand{\ptheme}[1]{
    {   
        \itshape
        %\tiny
        \centering
        \color{red} #1
        \smallskip
        
    }
}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{patercite}{
    enhanced,
    frame hidden,interior hidden,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0mm,
    right=0mm,
    left skip=2cm,
    borderline west={1.5mm}{0mm}{red},
    fontupper=\sffamily\scriptsize,
    }
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{patercite}{\vspace*{\fill}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{patercite}{\vspace*{\fill}\mbox{}}

\newcommand{\src}[1]{
    {   
        \sffamily
        \tiny
        \centering
        \color{red}\centering #1    
    }
    \par
}

\newcommand*\ruleline[1]{\par\noindent\raisebox{.8ex}{\makebox[\linewidth]{\hrulefill\hspace{1ex}\raisebox{-.8ex}{#1}\hspace{1ex}\hrulefill}}}

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
    \mainmatter

\section{Comentarios Patrísticos}

\subsection{San Cirilo de Alejandría, obispo}

\ptheme{Hablaban de la muerte que Jesús iba a consumar en Jerusalén}
\src{ Homilía 9 en la transfiguración del Señor: PG 77, 1011-1014.}

\begin{body}
    Jesús subió a una montaña con sus tres discípulos preferidos. Allí se transfiguró en un resplandor tan extraordinario y divino, que su vestido parecía hecho de luz. Se les aparecieron también Moisés y Elías conversando con Jesús: hablaban de su muerte, que iba a consumar en Jerusalén, o sea, del misterio de aquella salvación que había de operarse mediante su cuerpo, de aquella pasión –repito– que habría de consumarse en la cruz. Pues la verdad es que la ley de Moisés y los vaticinios de los santos profetas preanunciaron el misterio de Cristo: las losas de la ley lo describían como en imagen y veladamente; los profetas, en cambio, lo predicaron en distintas ocasiones y de muchas maneras, diciendo que en el momento oportuno aparecería en forma humana y aceptaría morir en la cruz por la salvación y la vida de todos.
    
    Y el hecho de que estuviesen allí presentes Moisés y Elías conversando con Jesús, quería indicar que la ley y los profetas son como los dos aliados de nuestro Señor Jesucristo, presentado por ellos como Dios a través de las cosas que habían preanunciado y que concordaban entre sí. En efecto, no disuenan de la ley los vaticinios de los profetas: y, a mi modo de ver, de esto hablaban Moisés y Elías, el más grande de los profetas.
    
    Habiéndose aparecido, no se mantuvieron en silencio, sino que hablaban de la gloria que el mismo Jesús iba a consumar en Jerusalén, a saber, de la pasión y de la cruz y, en ellas, vislumbraban también la resurrección. Pensando quizá el bienaventurado Pedro que había llegado el tiempo del reinado de Dios, gustoso se quedaría a vivir en la montaña; de hecho, y sin saber lo que decía, propone la construcción de tres tiendas. Pero aún no había llegado el fin de los tiempos, ni en la presente vida entrarán los santos a participar de la esperanza a ellos prometida. Dice, en efecto, Pablo: \textit{El trasformará nuestra condición humilde, según el modelo de su condición gloriosa}, es decir, de la condición gloriosa de Cristo.
    
    Ahora bien, estando estos planes todavía en sus comienzos, sin haber llegado aún a su culminación, sería una incongruencia que Cristo, que por amor había venido al mundo, abandonase el proyecto de padecer voluntariamente por él. Conservó, pues, aquella naturaleza infraceleste, con la que padeció la muerte según la carne y la borró por su resurrección de entre los muertos.
    
    Por lo demás y al margen de este admirable y arcano espectáculo de la gloria de Cristo, ocurrió además otro hecho útil y necesario para consolidar la fe en Cristo, no sólo de los discípulos, sino también de nosotros mismos. Allí, en lo alto, resonó efectivamente la voz del Padre que decía: \textit{Este es mi Hijo, el amado, mi predilecto. Escuchadlo}.
\end{body}

\begin{patercite}(\ldots) Éste es el misterio, saludable para nosotros, que ahora se ha cumplido en la montaña, ya que ahora nos reúne la muerte y, al mismo tiempo, la festividad de Cristo. Por esto, para que podamos penetrar, junto con los elegidos entre los discípulos inspirados por Dios, el sentido profundo de estos inefables y sagrados misterios, escuchemos la voz divina y sagrada que nos llama con insistencia desde lo alto, desde la cumbre de la montaña.
    
    Debemos apresurarnos a ir hacia allí –así me atrevo a decirlo– como Jesús, que allí en el cielo es nuestro guía y precursor, con quien brillaremos con nuestra mirada espiritualizada, renovados en cierta manera en los trazos de nuestra alma, hechos conformes a su imagen, y, como él, transfigurados continuamente y hechos partícipes de la naturaleza divina, y dispuestos para los dones celestiales.
    
    Corramos hacia allí, animosos y alegres, y penetremos en la intimidad de la nube, a imitación de Moisés y Elías, o de Santiago y Juan. Seamos como Pedro, arrebatado por la visión y aparición divina, transfigurado por aquella hermosa transfiguración, desasido del mundo, abstraído de la tierra; despojémonos de lo carnal, dejemos lo creado y volvámonos al Creador, al que Pedro, fuera de sí, dijo: \textit{Señor, ¡qué bien se está aquí!}
    
    Ciertamente, Pedro, en verdad qué bien se está aquí con Jesús; aquí nos quedaríamos para siempre. ¿Hay algo más dichoso, más elevado, más importante que estar con Dios, ser hechos conformes con él, vivir en la luz? Cada uno de nosotros, por el hecho de tener a Dios en sí y de ser transfigurado en su imagen divina, tiene derecho a exclamar con alegría: \textit{¡Qué bien se está aquí!} donde todo es resplandeciente, donde está el gozo, la felicidad y la alegría, donde el corazón disfruta de absoluta tranquilidad, serenidad y dulzura, donde vemos a (Cristo) Dios, donde él, junto con el Padre, pone su morada y dice, al entrar: \textit{Hoy ha sido la salvación de esta casa,} donde con Cristo se hallan acumulados los tesoros de los bienes eternos, donde hallamos reproducidas, como en un espejo, las imágenes de las realidades futuras.
    
    \textbf{Anastasio Sinaíta}, \textit{Sermón} en el día de la Transfiguración del Señor, 6-10: \textquote{Mélanges d’archeologie et d’histoire} 67 [1955], 241-244 (Breviario, 6 de agosto).
\end{patercite}

\end{document}
```

and the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is close to what you want. I don't have the ubuntu fonts installed so I commented on that line. Use the `\mfdsetup` to better adjust the result to your liking.

I assumed you wanted the red line towards the outer margin, on both odd and even pages.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex

\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} 

%%  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121315/how-do-i-draw-a-line-on-the-inner-margin-in-a-double-sided-document
\makeatletter 
\newrobustcmd*\if@mdf@pageodd@bar{%
    \zref@refused{mdf@pagelabel-\the\value{mdf@zref@counter}}%
    \ifodd\zref@extract{mdf@pagelabel-\the\value{mdf@zref@counter}}%
    {mdf@pagevalue}%
    \setlength\mdf@rightmargin@length{\mdf@outermargin@length}%
    \setlength\mdf@leftmargin@length{\mdf@innermargin@length}%
    \mdfsetup{%  oddpages           
        hidealllines=true,
        rightline=true,
        innerleftmargin = 0em,
        innerrightmargin = 1.5em,
        leftmargin=0pt,
}%
    \else
    \setlength\mdf@rightmargin@length{\mdf@innermargin@length}% interchange margins
    \setlength\mdf@leftmargin@length{\mdf@outermargin@length}%
    \mdfsetup{% evenpages
        leftmargin=2.3cm,
        hidealllines=true,
        leftline=true,
        innerleftmargin = 1.5em,
        innerrightmargin = 0em,}%
    \fi%
}
\newrobustcmd*\changepageodd{\let\if@mdf@pageodd\if@mdf@pageodd@bar}
\makeatother

% -------------------------------------------------------Packages
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\PassOptionsToPackage{main=spanish}{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[showframe, pass]{geometry}
% -------------------------------------------------------Book layout
\setstocksize{9in}{6in}
\settrimmedsize{9in}{6in}{*}
\setbinding{0.5in}
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.5in}{0.4in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.5in}{0.5in}{*}
\setheadfoot{12.07pt}{\footskip}
\checkandfixthelayout

% -------------------------------------------------------Global settings
%\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

% -------------------------------------------------------Fonts definition
\newfontfamily\notoserif{Noto Serif}        
\setmainfont{LinuxLibertineO}
%\setsansfont{Ubuntu}  % 

% -------------------------------------------------------Heading formats and styles
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\centering\normalfont} 
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\centering\huge\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand\secheadstyle{\scshape\centering\huge\sffamily\noindent}
\renewcommand\subsecheadstyle{\centering\Large\sffamily\bfseries\noindent}
\renewcommand\subsubsecheadstyle{\centering\large\sffamily\noindent\ruleline}
\setsecnumdepth{none}
\nouppercaseheads

\makeevenhead{headings}{\sffamily \scriptsize \thepage {\enspace \textemdash \enspace}\rightmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{headings}{}{}{\sffamily \scriptsize \leftmark {\enspace \textemdash \enspace} \thepage}
\makeevenfoot{headings}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{headings}{}{}{}

% Defined commands
%--------------------------------------------------------------------- Commands

\newcommand{\redtext}[1]{\renewcommand{\redtext}{#1}}
\newcommand{\smalltext}[1]{\renewcommand{\smalltext}{#1}}
\newcommand{\txtred}{\textcolor{red}}
\newcommand{\bfred}{\textcolor{red}}
\newcommand{\rred}{\mbox{}\hfill\txtred}
\newcommand{\h}{\hspace{5mm}}
\newcommand{\hl}{\hspace{10mm}}
\newcommand{\txtsmall}{\small}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------Body styles
\newenvironment{body}{%
    \addvspace{\topsep}% Space above
}{%
    \unskip\par
    \addvspace{\topsep}% Space below
    %\needspace{15\baselineskip}
}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------Pater styles

\newcommand{\ptheme}[1]{%
    {%   
        \itshape
        %\tiny
        \centering
        \color{red} #1
        \smallskip        
    }
}


\mdfdefinestyle{RedRule}{% use this to change the setup of the frame common to odd or even page
    outermargin = 2cm, % 2cm left margin 
    innertopmargin = 4pt,
    innerbottommargin = 4pt,
    rightmargin=0pt,
    linecolor=red,
    linewidth = 1.5pt,  
    skipabove=10pt,
    skipbelow=20pt,
    font={\sffamily\scriptsize},
    settings={\changepageodd}
}

\newenvironment{patercite}{%
    \vspace*{\fill}% 
    \begin{mdframed}[style=RedRule]
        \hspace{\parindent}
}
    {\end{mdframed}}{% 
    \vspace*{\fill}%
}

\newcommand{\src}[1]{%
    {%   
        \sffamily
        \tiny
        \centering
        \color{red}\centering #1    
    }
    \par
}

\newcommand*\ruleline[1]{\par\noindent\raisebox{.8ex}{\makebox[\linewidth]{\hrulefill\hspace{1ex}\raisebox{-.8ex}{#1}\hspace{1ex}\hrulefill}}}

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
    
\mainmatter

\section{Comentarios Patrísticos}

\subsection{San Cirilo de Alejandría, obispo}

\ptheme{Hablaban de la muerte que Jesús iba a consumar en Jerusalén}
\src{ Homilía 9 en la transfiguración del Señor: PG 77, 1011-1014.}

\begin{body}
    Jesús subió a una montaña con sus tres discípulos preferidos. Allí se transfiguró en un resplandor tan extraordinario y divino, que su vestido parecía hecho de luz. Se les aparecieron también Moisés y Elías conversando con Jesús: hablaban de su muerte, que iba a consumar en Jerusalén, o sea, del misterio de aquella salvación que había de operarse mediante su cuerpo, de aquella pasión –repito– que habría de consumarse en la cruz. Pues la verdad es que la ley de Moisés y los vaticinios de los santos profetas preanunciaron el misterio de Cristo: las losas de la ley lo describían como en imagen y veladamente; los profetas, en cambio, lo predicaron en distintas ocasiones y de muchas maneras, diciendo que en el momento oportuno aparecería en forma humana y aceptaría morir en la cruz por la salvación y la vida de todos.
    
    Y el hecho de que estuviesen allí presentes Moisés y Elías conversando con Jesús, quería indicar que la ley y los profetas son como los dos aliados de nuestro Señor Jesucristo, presentado por ellos como Dios a través de las cosas que habían preanunciado y que concordaban entre sí. En efecto, no disuenan de la ley los vaticinios de los profetas: y, a mi modo de ver, de esto hablaban Moisés y Elías, el más grande de los profetas.
    
    Habiéndose aparecido, no se mantuvieron en silencio, sino que hablaban de la gloria que el mismo Jesús iba a consumar en Jerusalén, a saber, de la pasión y de la cruz y, en ellas, vislumbraban también la resurrección. Pensando quizá el bienaventurado Pedro que había llegado el tiempo del reinado de Dios, gustoso se quedaría a vivir en la montaña; de hecho, y sin saber lo que decía, propone la construcción de tres tiendas. Pero aún no había llegado el fin de los tiempos, ni en la presente vida entrarán los santos a participar de la esperanza a ellos prometida. Dice, en efecto, Pablo: \textit{El trasformará nuestra condición humilde, según el modelo de su condición gloriosa}, es decir, de la condición gloriosa de Cristo.
    
    Ahora bien, estando estos planes todavía en sus comienzos, sin haber llegado aún a su culminación, sería una incongruencia que Cristo, que por amor había venido al mundo, abandonase el proyecto de padecer voluntariamente por él. Conservó, pues, aquella naturaleza infraceleste, con la que padeció la muerte según la carne y la borró por su resurrección de entre los muertos.
    
    Por lo demás y al margen de este admirable y arcano espectáculo de la gloria de Cristo, ocurrió además otro hecho útil y necesario para consolidar la fe en Cristo, no sólo de los discípulos, sino también de nosotros mismos. Allí, en lo alto, resonó efectivamente la voz del Padre que decía: \textit{Este es mi Hijo, el amado, mi predilecto. Escuchadlo}.
\end{body}

\begin{patercite}
    (\ldots) Éste es el misterio, saludable para nosotros, que ahora se ha cumplido en la montaña, ya que ahora nos reúne la muerte y, al mismo tiempo, la festividad de Cristo. Por esto, para que podamos penetrar, junto con los elegidos entre los discípulos inspirados por Dios, el sentido profundo de estos inefables y sagrados misterios, escuchemos la voz divina y sagrada que nos llama con insistencia desde lo alto, desde la cumbre de la montaña.
    
    Debemos apresurarnos a ir hacia allí –así me atrevo a decirlo– como Jesús, que allí en el cielo es nuestro guía y precursor, con quien brillaremos con nuestra mirada espiritualizada, renovados en cierta manera en los trazos de nuestra alma, hechos conformes a su imagen, y, como él, transfigurados continuamente y hechos partícipes de la naturaleza divina, y dispuestos para los dones celestiales.
    
    Corramos hacia allí, animosos y alegres, y penetremos en la intimidad de la nube, a imitación de Moisés y Elías, o de Santiago y Juan. Seamos como Pedro, arrebatado por la visión y aparición divina, transfigurado por aquella hermosa transfiguración, desasido del mundo, abstraído de la tierra; despojémonos de lo carnal, dejemos lo creado y volvámonos al Creador, al que Pedro, fuera de sí, dijo: \textit{Señor, ¡qué bien se está aquí!}
    
    Ciertamente, Pedro, en verdad qué bien se está aquí con Jesús; aquí nos quedaríamos para siempre. ¿Hay algo más dichoso, más elevado, más importante que estar con Dios, ser hechos conformes con él, vivir en la luz? Cada uno de nosotros, por el hecho de tener a Dios en sí y de ser transfigurado en su imagen divina, tiene derecho a exclamar con alegría: \textit{¡Qué bien se está aquí!} donde todo es resplandeciente, donde está el gozo, la felicidad y la alegría, donde el corazón disfruta de absoluta tranquilidad, serenidad y dulzura, donde vemos a (Cristo) Dios, donde él, junto con el Padre, pone su morada y dice, al entrar: \textit{Hoy ha sido la salvación de esta casa,} donde con Cristo se hallan acumulados los tesoros de los bienes eternos, donde hallamos reproducidas, como en un espejo, las imágenes de las realidades futuras.
    
    \textbf{Anastasio Sinaíta}, \textit{Sermón} en el día de la Transfiguración del Señor, 6-10: \textquote{Mélanges d’archeologie et d’histoire} 67 [1955], 241-244 (Breviario, 6 de agosto).
\end{patercite}

\subsection{San Cirilo de Alejandría, obispo II}

\ptheme{Hablaban de la muerte que Jesús iba a consumar en Jerusalén}
\src{ Homilía 9 en la transfiguración del Señor: PG 77, 1011-1014.}

\begin{body}
    Jesús subió a una montaña con sus tres discípulos preferidos. Allí se transfiguró en un resplandor tan extraordinario y divino, que su vestido parecía hecho de luz. Se les aparecieron también Moisés y Elías conversando con Jesús: hablaban de su muerte, que iba a consumar en Jerusalén, o sea, del misterio de aquella salvación que había de operarse mediante su cuerpo, de aquella pasión –repito– que habría de consumarse en la cruz. Pues la verdad es que la ley de Moisés y los vaticinios de los santos profetas preanunciaron el misterio de Cristo: las losas de la ley lo describían como en imagen y veladamente; los profetas, en cambio, lo predicaron en distintas ocasiones y de muchas maneras, diciendo que en el momento oportuno aparecería en forma humana y aceptaría morir en la cruz por la salvación y la vida de todos.
    
\end{body}

\begin{patercite}
    (\ldots) Éste es el misterio, saludable para nosotros, que ahora se ha cumplido en la montaña, ya que ahora nos reúne la muerte y, al mismo tiempo, la festividad de Cristo. Por esto, para que podamos penetrar, junto con los elegidos entre los discípulos inspirados por Dios, el sentido profundo de estos inefables y sagrados misterios, escuchemos la voz divina y sagrada que nos llama con insistencia desde lo alto, desde la cumbre de la montaña.
            
    Ciertamente, Pedro, en verdad qué bien se está aquí con Jesús; aquí nos quedaríamos para siempre. ¿Hay algo más dichoso, más elevado, más importante que estar con Dios, ser hechos conformes con él, vivir en la luz? Cada uno de nosotros, por el hecho de tener a Dios en sí y de ser transfigurado en su imagen divina, tiene derecho a exclamar con alegría: \textit{¡Qué bien se está aquí!} donde todo es resplandeciente, donde está el gozo, la felicidad y la alegría, donde el corazón disfruta de absoluta tranquilidad, serenidad y dulzura, donde vemos a (Cristo) Dios, donde él, junto con el Padre, pone su morada y dice, al entrar: \textit{Hoy ha sido la salvación de esta casa,} donde con Cristo se hallan acumulados los tesoros de los bienes eternos, donde hallamos reproducidas, como en un espejo, las imágenes de las realidades futuras.
    
    \textbf{Anastasio Sinaíta}, \textit{Sermón} en el día de la Transfiguración del Señor, 6-10: \textquote{Mélanges d’archeologie et d’histoire} 67 [1955], 241-244 (Breviario, 6 de agosto).
\end{patercite}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works only with odd pages, but not working with even pages.

Comment: On even pages, you would like the red line right or left? Could you expand your MWE to show content on even pages? The red line will stay on a single page or cross pages?