mdframed package modified - with problem for twoside pagebreak and not correct frame break
I tried to modify the mdframed.sty file for the intention of:

to have outer bars for special parts of a text
for twoside display (inner, outer) instead of left, right.

I am not a developer and need a bit support for this task.
The MWE is this:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[twoside,paperwidth=180mm,paperheight=250mm,top=25mm,includehead,bottom=35mm,outer=35mm,inner=30mm,headheight=14pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{TwoSideHeading}{\fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\rmfamily\thepage}
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\scshape Two Side Heading}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[usetwoside=true,framemethod=tikz]{mdframed-modified}% by Thomkrates
\input{mdframed-hack-twoside_Test.tex}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{TwoSideHeading}

\begin{mdframed}[style=BetonungAussen]
\lipsum[3]
\end{mdframed}%
\lipsum[1]
\begin{mdframed}[style=BetonungAussen]
\lipsum[3]
\end{mdframed}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{mdframed}[style=BetonungAussen]
\lipsum[5]
\end{mdframed}
You see that the pagebreak is not correct. On page 1 the outer bar is too long. On page 2 the skip after the framed text is too small.

\end{document}

The file mdframed-hack-twoside_Test.tex is this:
% See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121315/how-do-i-draw-a-line-on-the-inner-margin-in-a-double-sided-document
% modified for Outer-Bars:
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*\if@mdf@pageodd@bar{%
    \zref@refused{mdf@pagelabel-\the\value{mdf@zref@counter}}%
    \ifodd\zref@extract{mdf@pagelabel-\the\value{mdf@zref@counter}}%
    {mdf@pagevalue}%
    \setlength\mdf@leftmargin@length{\mdf@outermargin@length}%
    \setlength\mdf@rightmargin@length{\mdf@innermargin@length}%
    \setlength\mdf@innerrightmargin@length{\mdf@outeroddmargin@length}%
    \setlength\mdf@innerleftmargin@length{\mdf@inneroddmargin@length}%
    \mdfsetup{hidealllines=true,rightline=true}%
    \else
    \setlength\mdf@leftmargin@length{\mdf@innermargin@length}%
    \setlength\mdf@rightmargin@length{\mdf@outermargin@length}%
    \setlength\mdf@innerrightmargin@length{\mdf@innerevenmargin@length}%
    \setlength\mdf@innerleftmargin@length{\mdf@outerevenmargin@length}%
    \mdfsetup{hidealllines=true,leftline=true}%
    \fi%
}
\newrobustcmd*\changepageodd{\let\if@mdf@pageodd\if@mdf@pageodd@bar}
\makeatother
%
\mdfdefinestyle{BetonungAussen}{%
    linecolor=black,
    %
    outerlinewidth=1.5pt,
    outermargin=0em,
    innermargin=0em,
    leftmargin=0em,
    rightmargin=0em,
    %
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    rightline=false,
    leftline=true,
    %
    innertopmargin=0pt,
    innerbottommargin=0pt,
    innerrightmargin=1em,
%
   outeroddmargin= 1em,
   inneroddmargin= 0em,
   innerleftmargin=0em, 
   outerevenmargin=1em,
   innerevenmargin=0em,
%
   skipabove=\topskip,%0.5\baselineskip,
   skipbelow=\topskip,%0.5\baselineskip,% no functionality?
   settings={\changepageodd}
   %    
}

And the complete mdframed-modified.sty file is this:
(modified parts are marked with modified)
Please look at my OneDrive Cloud folder:
Exchange-folder_Thomkrates_TeXLaTeX-forum
QUESTION: How can the pagebreak result of the outer bar frame be improved?

Given that mdframed has not been updated sidne 2010, it is probably a better udea to move to tcolorbox as it is actively maintained.

Ok, thank you. I will have a look. And eventually come back.

If possible, can you provide the requirement as an image? sorry not able to understand correctly
